# Check Constraint with Parent Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, check-constraints

I have a parent-child set of tables. The parent table, `interaction` has columns `id` and `start_time`. The child table, `meeting`, has columns `interaction_id` and `end_time`.

I want to add a constraint that the end times of all meetings should be AFTER their respective start times. Can this be achieved in a check constraint with a `SELECT` statement, or should this be enforced differently (possibly at the application level)?

By the way I'm running the most recent version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Constraints can enforce rules on Table Level but since you are trying to enforce a business rule between two tables you need to Create an `Instead of Insert Trigger` that fires and check the Records in your parent table that if it satisfies your business rule either case it will insert the date or not.